# Is it allowed for a boy and girl to chat in college?

Tags: modesty

As long as they are respectful and do not talk online and do not text, and do not talk about forbidden topics or flirt, or be alone or touch each other or do anything that makes the other, or themselves, uncomfortable? I have such an acquaintance, and I am a brother. I fear I am breaking the rule on not being alone because we often chat in Turkish (well, Turkic, we're from different ethnicities, and we chat in different dialects) and no one in uni understands us (unless another one from our ethnic groups come by, which has never happened as far as im aware) what is the etiquette for boy girl interaction? i live in a western country.

Comment: Is the conversation due to any unavoidable necessity or not?

Comment: we dont have to talk, we choose to. we dont even share any classes.

Comment: Does she dress according to Islam? Because, in one of your previous question, you said women in your country rarely wear Hijab.

Comment: She does not cover her hair, but she dresses modestly.

Comment: Well, we're commanded to lower our gaze in front of non-mahram. This becomes even more necessary if the non-mahram hasn't dressed Islamically. Because, it causes Fitnah. The more you do it, the more you will take it casually. There is a reason why Fitnah is regarded to be more severe than killing by Allah Himself. If gazing upon them is restricted to strict necessity then you know what the ruling on chatting is.

Comment: On a Nurcu (Nurist, from Nur cemaat a jamaat that revived Islam in Turkey after the Kemalist attacks on Islam) website I got this: https://questionsonislam.com/question/what-does-islam-says-about-chatting-chatting-opposite-sex-haram-or-not

Comment: but ill keep your advice in mind, i felt afraid of Allah that I was committing haram, so I asked Allah to guide me, I'll do istikhara.

Answer (score -1):

· As long as they are respectful and do not talk online and do not text, and do not talk about forbidden topics or flirt,

Comment: Excuse me ma’dam. But, do you have any clear evidences for which you claim? In here it is like in police, you need to bring clear evidences for whatever claim you utter. As long as you do not have a evidence at least, then your claim cannot be the right answer. Remember, always bring clear evidences for whatever you claim, so that the questioner can be relieved and to truly believe in Truth.